# iOS 7 - Tab Bar Disappears After Back Button

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5

Issue:

I have a Tab Bar Controller and in one of the tabs is a table view. Upon clicking a table cell, they proceed to a new view. If they click back from this view, they return back to the table view, but the Tab Bar DISAPPEARS!

Notes:

-Further yet, the view is still connected in the storyboard after I've shut the program down, but the Tab Bar isn't visible on that view

-The icon for this view appears differently if I reconnect it to the tab bar controller, the other views have a default "icon" which is a square, where as this view says "first" with a circle

Story Board layout attached

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If they click back from this view, they return back to the table view, but the Tab Bar DISAPPEARS!

I'm guessing that the way you set up this "return back" in the storyboard is wrong. You want to dismiss the modal view controller at this point (or use an unwind segue). Instead, I'm guessing you've drawn a *new* segue from the new view back to the table view, so you are getting a *new* table view lying on top of everything, and of course it is not the same as the one that's inside the tab bar controller.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! To anyone who wants to know how to implement an unwind segue, I used the following video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJK_4RriR34